# Handle TextBox event such as Text_changed in ViewModel

Tags: events, mvvm, textbox

For handling Button Click in View-model we hook Button-Command with a ViewModel Property.

```
<Button Command="ButtonCommand"/>


class MyViewModel
{
   ICommand _buttonCommand;
   public MyViewModel()
   {
     _buttonCommand=new CommandHandler(() => Buttonfunction(), "true");
   }

   public ICommand ButtonCommand
   {
    get{ return _buttonCommand;}    
   }

   private void Buttonfunction
   { //do something. }
}

public class CommandHandler : ICommand
{
 private Action _action;
 private bool _canExecute;
 public CommandHandler(Action action, bool canExecute)
 {
    _action = action;
    _canExecute = canExecute;
 }

 public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
 {
    return _canExecute;
 }

 public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

 public void Execute(object parameter)
 {
    _action();
 }
}
```

Similarly What can be done for TextBox events.
How can we Bind a Command with TextBox Event in .NET 3.5.

```
<TextBox TextChanged=?/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must bind it to a property first, Then use the setter of that property as your text change event.
In your xaml:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" />
```

In your Viewmodel

```cs
private string _name;

public string Name
{
    get
    {
        return _name;
    }
    set
    {
        _name = value;
        yourTextChangeEvent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually it should be `<TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" />`, but the general idea is correct.

Comment: Thanks Hossein. How can we achieve this with commands and events.?And what will be the better way of doing this, with commands and events or as you mentioned above.

Comment: @Vijay You can't, In MVVM you own the properties. So You don't have to use normal events. you can create them by binding a property to your view and listening to it's changes. it's just how MVVM works. don't worry you'll get used to it pretty soon. One more thing, The commands are not exactly a Click Event. they are the actions of your ViewModel so they must be related to the concept of your ViewModel.